# Using Reflection for Accessing Private Members

Tags: c#, reflection

Short story.
Someone in a project I'm involved in, decided to use reflection for accessing a member of another class from another DLL. Why? laziness.
I have a good (bad?) habit of eliminating all Resharper warnings before checking in files.
One day, I saw a private member that was not used anywhere in the class it belonged to...so, shift+delete and the member is gone.
Two months after, a showstopper from one of our production sites.
It took us 1 week to find our that the problem was that the reflection code could not find the private member and wrapping code was not good enough.
By happen, it was also a scenario that was not covered by our automatic testing.

Which code analysis tool do you recommend where I can setup rules for such use cases?

Thanks

Comment: Your 2nd question is subjective and is off topic for this site, please remove it from the question.

Comment: Answer: Fire the idiot that used reflection to access a private member in production code. If he's already fired, proceed to poop on his lawn.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - that's interesting suggestion... Also probably should be directed to OP instead: main reason people have to use reflection to get to private methods is refusal of API providers to expose necessary functionality. So to avoid that DLL better provided useful complete API...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if you work in an environment where that is the main reason people use reflection, I implore you to find another gig.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot What are your good reasons to use reflection to call private methods/get private fields?

Comment: None. There are none. There are usages of reflection which don't involve invoking private members at all which are perfectly cromulent, however.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov But the OP said that he was the one who removed the private member - which implies that he, and the guy who used reflection both have access to the source code. So why didn't the other guy just go modify the API to have a public property?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - I'm not sure how being able to call private member via reflection implies access to the source code... I.e. anyone can call any private members from System.Dll via reflection but number of people who can change its code is very limited. Why other guy did not change code - plenty of possible reasons - no access, tried in the past and was told to @@@@ (basically not), owner of the DLL had its own idea what is useful, different time line when code can be published... I'm not saying calling private methods is ok this way, just blame is often 50/50 on both parties.

Comment: @@AlexeiLevenkov the other guy did have access to the code. We're working in the same project. Why he didn't add it to the API is a good question. He should have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no tool as there is no way to test for this on the DLL side of things.

The reason you keep some methods are public and some methods are private is so you can have a published contract that people consuming your DLL can use. What you do internally in your DLL should be a black box that no one should have any knowledge or caring about what is happening.

The only way to "test" for this is on the caller side writing bog standard unit tests for any function that uses reflection. Then you must make sure the shipping version of the DLL matches the version you did your unit tests against.

As for the person who used reflection, have him justify his reasons and if not statisfactory put him on probation requiring all code he submits to be reviewed more thoroughly before it is allowed to be checked in. If he does not stop doing things like this (either using reflection when he absolutely should not, or not writing through unit tests for his code that must use reflection to be sure that the code he is calling has not changed internally) ***he should be fired***.

Comment: This is the greatest answer I have ever read on SO.  And, you are 100% correct in it too.

Comment: You just gave me an idea. I think we can restrict the programmers from working with .NET reflection API. Instead we can create a proxy API for the reflection code and implement automatic generated testing according to specific calls used in the proxy API.